# Nested StimulusJS scopes / controller issue / HTML 5 template tag

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

I have a basic Rails app with a nested association and I am doing a standard 'line items' type view where I am dynamically adding and removing rows from a template tag.  I have a select that triggers a AJAX call to replace all the nested row selects (the context changed).  The expenditure controller handles the overall form and the nested-form controller is used on other pages to handle the adding and removal of rows:

```
<div data-controller="expenditure nested-form">

  <select data-target="expenditure.budget" data-action="change->expenditure#update_related"></select>

  <table>
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
      inserted rows... 
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select data-target="expenditure.budgetItemSelect"></select>
        </td>
      </tr>

    <template data-target="nested-form.template">
      <tr data-new_record="true">
        <td>
          <select data-target="expenditure.budgetItemSelect"></select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </template>

    </tbody>
  </table>  

</div>
```

It works fine.  I can add and remove rows and if I change the `expenditure.budget` select all the `expenditure.budgetItemSelect` targets get updated EXCEPT for the one inside the template.  It's as if it's missing from the entire scope of the controller.  I had them nested before but now have them in the same div `data-controller="expenditure nested-form"` to double check and it still doesn't work.  Checked spelling and even tried removing the `data-target="nested-form.template"`.  No errors in the browser console.  Am I missing something obvious here?

**UPDATE**

Hmmm... it seems that the `template` tag is read only and NOT part of the DOM which is why this fails.

I managed a hack where I replaced the contents of the entire template but that seems to break the controller that adds / deletes the rows ‍♂️.

**UPDATE 2**

I found a workaround - If someone can improve this code I will accept this as a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with the `<template>` tag in HTML5.

I have a workaround but it's ugly.

```
<div data-controller="expenditure nested-form">

  <select data-target="expenditure.budget" data-action="change->expenditure#update_related"></select>

  <table>
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
      inserted rows... 
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select data-target="expenditure.budgetItemSelect"></select>
        </td>
      </tr>

    <template id="expenditure_items_template">
      <tr data-new_record="true">
        <td>
          <select data-target="expenditure.budgetItemSelect"></select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </template>
    <script type="text/template" data-target="nested-form.template" id="expenditure_items_template_script">
    </script>

    </tbody>
  </table>  

</div>
```

Here is what I did in my controller:

```
// find the template
var template = document.getElementById("expenditure_items_template");

// load the template contents
var new_template = document.importNode(template.content, true);

// replace the select with my new content (off screen)
```

new_template.getElementById('expenditure_expenditure_items_attributes_NEW_RECORD_budget_item_id').innerHTML = select.innerHTML;

// clear the new script place holder
    document.getElementById("expenditure_items_template_script").innerHTML = "";

// set the new updated template into the script tag
document.getElementById("expenditure_items_template_script").appendChild(new_template);

I basically have two templates - one `<template>` which holds the raw HTML and the second `<script>` that works with Stimulus.

Comment: Note the `<script>` needs to be out side of your form tag.